Distance of a Point from a Line in 2D in a General $L^p$ Space $(p \geq 1)$
Given a line  $y = \alpha x$ and a point $(a, b)$ in $\mathbb{R}^2$,
I derived the distance formulas for the $L^1$, $L^2$, and $L^\infty$ norms in closed form as follows:

$L^1$ distance: $\space \space d_{L^1} = |a \alpha - b|\cdot \min(1,\frac{1}{|\alpha|})$

$L^2$ distance: $\space \space d_{L^2} = \frac{|a \alpha - b|}{\sqrt{\alpha^2 + 1}}$

$L^\infty$ distance: $\space\space d_{L^\infty} = \frac{|a \alpha - b|}{|\alpha|+1}$


However, I am curious if there is a known closed form for the distance in a general $L^p$ space, or at least a more general result. Does a closed-form expression for arbitrary $p \geq 1$ exist, or are there known bounds for approximating this distance?

In your answer for $L^\infty$, the denominator should be $1+|\alpha|$ rather than $|1+\alpha|$. Indeed, the latter doesn’t make sense for $\alpha=-1$.

Yeah sorry, made a mistake...

For general $1<p<\infty$, we can do the following:
First, when $\alpha = 0$ or $\infty$, i.e. when the line is x-axis ($y=0$) or y-axis ($x=0$), the shortest distance is simply $b$ or $a$, respectively. So let’s assume $0<|\alpha|<\infty$. Let’s further assume $\alpha>0$. (The other sign can be dealt with similarly.)
If the point $(a,b)$ is on the line, then the answer is zero, so let’s assume it’s not. Let us further assume that $b < \alpha a$, i.e., $(a,b)$ is “below” the line. (The “above” case can be dealt with similarly.) Then, the point $(x,y)$ on the line that’s closest to $(a,b)$ in $L^p$-distance is in the second quadrant of $(a,b)$, i.e. $x<a$ and $y>b$.
Let $(t,\alpha t)$ be an arbitrary point in the line parametrised by $t\in \mathbb R$. Then the $L^p$-distance between this point and $(a,b)$ is
$$
f(t)=[(a-t)^p + (\alpha t - b)^p]^{1/p}.
$$
Our goal is to find a $t$ in the interval $(\frac{b}{\alpha},a)$ that minimises $f(t)$.
For $1<p<\infty$ and $t\in (\frac{b}{\alpha},a)$, $f(t)$ is differentiable, so we can use calculus to find the local minimum:
$$
f’(t) = [(a-t)^p + (\alpha t - b)^p]^{(1-p)/p} [-(a-t)^{p-1} + \alpha(\alpha t-b)^{p-1}] =0.
$$
Solving for $t$ gives
$$
t = \frac{a+ \alpha^{1/(p-1)} b}{1+\alpha^{p/(p-1)}}.
$$
Substituting this into $f(t)$ gives the shortest distance to be
$$
\frac{a\alpha-b}{(1+\alpha^{p/(p-1)})^{(p-1)/p}}.
$$
More generally, the shortest $L^p$-distance between $(a,b)$ and the line is given by
$$
\frac{|a\alpha-b|}{(1+|\alpha|^{p/(p-1)})^{(p-1)/p}}.
$$
